How do I get input values of a modal form from another file/module function?


function createForm() {
  const addTaskForm = document.createElement('form');
  //code that creates the form
  const titleInput = document.createElement('input');
  const descInput = document.createElement('textarea');
  const dueDateInput = document.createElement('input');
  const priorityInput = document.createElement('input');
  const confirmButton = document.createElement('button');
  confirmButton.textContent = 'confirm';
  const cancelButton = document.createElement('button');
  cancelButton.textContent = 'cancel';
  addTaskForm.append(
    titleInput,
    descInput,
    dueDateInput,
    priorityInput,
    confirmButton,
    cancelButton,
  );
  return addTaskForm;
}

function loadAddTaskDiv() {
  const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
  const div = document.createElement('div');
;
  const addTaskForm = createForm();
  div.append(addTaskForm);
  wrapper.append(div);
  return div;
}

loadAddTaskDiv();
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper"></div>
    </body>

    </html>



I am creating a todo project and I am having a problem trying to get the input values from the user since I am imporitng the module which creates the form.
I am imporitng the module which creates the form div from another file and I am not able to get the user inputs while using that div in the current file.
github repo:-
https://github.com/Muzzu153/todo-list
link to the page:-
https://muzzu153.github.io/todo-list/

"Now how do I get the values of the input elements from the user into this file and other file as well. " - that doesn't make any sense. When you import the loadAddTaskDiv function from the addTaskDiv.js file, you are aquiring that resource (the loadAddTaskDiv function definition), and the browser will execute the JavaScript code. You are not writing anything to any "file". I do not know what do you mean by "getting the user input value into a file" - you may be able to store that piece of information in a JavaScript variable and access it later.

@NapoleonBonaparte It definitely doesn'nt make sense when I read it again, sorry my bad for not able to frame it poperly. "you may be able to store that piece of information in a JavaScript variable and access it later" - I think this is what I want, I can store those values and return them ig but I only wanted for that file to do is create the div and not return any values. Was trying for the single responsibilty concept :).

@NapoleonBonaparte. But I've thought about it and getting the values is also part of the adding task so there's no problem doing that. But I've also tried that, storing them in variable but still not able get the values. I'll edit the code above.

@traktor yess I have edited the question for how I am using the event handling. And yes, I am using event bubbling for event handling.

Please create a minimal complete verifiable example of the issue as a cutdown code snippet which runs without compile time errors. In this case, commenting out he import and export statements between the two parts of JavaScript code is needed to get it to run as a snippet. This should also establish if the use of modules relates to the issue or not.

@traktor I do have edited it, sorry man for not able to expain my problem. Simply put I am importing the form module from different file so how do i get the input values from the user? where and how do I store them and access them

@traktor even if I have added the snipped I dont think it will be of any use. Since I guess it's related to import/export. Maybe thats the case or not, i really can't get it, I just want to get values from the user and the I am importing the form div. But how do I get the values, I have tried to export the inputElement.value but didn't help. I want to create a task using those values and push the task into the array list so that I can display it on the screen.

I think you might have to re-work your project, because there are so many problems with your code. I do not think the problem lies with the import/export statements in your code (although it is no longer present as of your newest edit), but rather how you are handling events, and your understanding of the variable e is binded to. I would suggest you re-learn how events work and organize your code in components, so that it can be modularized (which you did fairly well). If you don't mind, put your code in a GitHub repo and I'll take a look at it with more context.

@NapoleonBonaparte thanks for the reply, I have linked the github repo in the post, I'll also link it here and I can also publish it using github pages so that you can understand it with more context with how the pages looks and all that. https://github.com/Muzzu153/todo-list

@traktor thanks guys both of you for your replies.

@NapoleonBonaparte I have tried to seperate the logic with DOM stuff, so the logic is in ./src/modules/  and everything related DOM is in ./src/DOM

Accessing form data
User values entered into form elements are held as property values of the form element in the DOM. They are unrelated to the code location or file or module that created the form in the first place.
The usual way of getting would be to listen for the submit event fired on the form when the "Confirm" button is clicked - and it's already a submit button in the code.
There are caveats to watch out for

don't respond to submit events generated by pressing Enter while typing in an input box,
prevent submission from taking place when processing the submit event - the entire page is likely to reload if submission is allowed to occur.


Here's some code based on the github source that prints user data entered on the console:
loadAddTaskDiv.js

Listen for submit events fired on the new task form.
 const createAddTaskModalForm = () => {
  // creating the form for user input
 const addTaskForm = document.createElement('form');
 addTaskForm.addEventListener("submit", checkAddTask); // add submit listener
 ... // continue with existing code


Code a submit listener to prevent form submission and only respond to the "Confirm" key:
 const checkAddTask = event => {
   event.preventDefault();
   if( document.activeElement.id ==='confirm-button') { // not an input box
      validateAddTask( event.currentTarget);
   }
 };


Initiate Processing user inputs after the "Confirm" button is pushed (it's a submit button). The following code is for demonstration of getting input values as text. It does not try to validate them or create a new task object in the task list:
const validateAddTask = form => {

  ['new-task-title', 'new-task-description','new-task-date','new-task-priority']
  .forEach( name => {
     const value = form[name].value;
     console.log(`${name} = ${value}`);
   });
};




Thanks for taking time and going through my repo, and thanks for explaining this, i tried and was able to console.log the input value. One question tho, how do I store these value in variables so that I can pass them as arguments in the createTask() function  which will return a task. Or just  directly pass the formElement.value as arguments without storing them so that the createTask() can return a task and then add that task into the array?

I really really appreciate your and others effort. And I am grateful to you all. Thanks!

You could do either of the options you suggested for store form values. A hint for your consideration: use  the same names for properties of the task object and the names (and possibly id's) of the form's inputs to enter their values to simplify the code. For example task.priority = form.priority.value does away with having to use array  notation look up of names with hyphens in them.
